# Creating UML diagram for Shoe class

Tags: java, class, constructor, uml

I am taking an online class and I am having some trouble with this assignment.

I'm having trouble with part 1 "A default constructor that initializes each attribute to some reasonable default value for non-existent shoes."

Here's what I have:

Shoe

---

(-) style: String

(-) color: String

(-) size: Integer

---

(+) setSyle (s: String)

(+) setColor (c: String)

(+) setSize (z: Integer)

(+) getSyle () : String

(+) getColor () : String

(+) getSize () : Integer

Assignment:

The Showy Shiny Shoe Store sells different styles of shoes, such as sandals and walking shoes. Each style of shoe is offered in different colors, such as brown and black. Available shoe sizes range from size 5 to size 11, in both whole and half sizes. Design an object-oriented computer program by doing the following:

Part I

.      Create the class diagram for the Shoe class that contains the style of the shoes, the color of the shoes, and the size. Examples of valid values for the style are "sandals" and "walking". Examples of valid values for the color are "brown" and "black". Examples of valid values for the size are 6.5 and 9.0. Be sure to choose the most appropriate data type for the attributes. For this class definition, include the following:

- A default constructor that initializes each attribute to some reasonable default value for non-existent shoes.
- Another constructor method that has a parameter for each data member.  This constructor initializes each attribute to the value provided when an object of this type is instantiated.
- Accessor and mutator methods for each attribute.
  Part II -

Write the pseudo code for the Shoe class that was designed in the class diagram in part I.
Part III -

Write the pseudocode for the application program for the shoe store with a main() module that instantiates two objects of the Shoe class.  The first object should be named nerdShoes and use the default constructor.  The second object should be named coolShoes and use the second constructor to initialize the style to "sandals", the color to "brown", and the size to 8.5. Include the following instructions in the main() method, in the order specified below:
A call to set the color of the nerdShoes to "tan".
A call to set the style of the nerdShoes to “walking"
A call to set the size of the nerdShoes to 9.5.
A statement that displays the style of the nerdShoes, using the appropriate method call.
A call to change the color of the coolShoes to "purple".
A statement that displays the style of the coolShoes, using the appropriate method call.

Comment: It would be nice if you could strip down your problem to a simple question and not spam us with your whole assignment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I don't answer with entire code, as this is something you need to work on. You learn more and better when you try by yourself.

But I will send my suggestion as I like UML questions... (though this was simple UML in it).

But I m wondering why using size as Integer? You mention you need half sizes ? My suggestion would be using e.g. `float`.

[image: Shoe UML]

```
package theshowyshinyshoestore;

public class Shoe {
  String style;
  float size;
  String color;

  public Shoe() {
      setStyle("unknown");
      setSize(0);
      setColor("unknown");
  }

  public Shoe(String style, float size, String color) {
      setStyle(style);
      setSize(size);
      setColor(color);
  }

  public void setStyle( String style ) {
      //perform checks for valid style
      //...
      this.style = style;
  }

  public void setSize( float size ) {
      //perform checks for valid size
      //...
      this.size = size;
  }

  public void setColor( String color ) {
      //perform checks for valid colors
      //...
      this.color = color;
  }

  public String getStyle() {
    return this.style;
  }

  public float getSize() {
    return this.size;
  }

  public String getColor() {
    return this.color;
  }


  public String toString() {
    return "Style: " + this.style + " Size: " + this.size + " Color: " + this.color;
  }


  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Shoe nerdShoes = new Shoe();
    Shoe coolShoes = new Shoe("sandals", 8.5f, "brown");
    System.out.println( "nerdShoes: " + nerdShoes );
    System.out.println( "coolShoes: " + coolShoes );

    nerdShoes.setColor("tan");
    nerdShoes.setStyle("walking");
    nerdShoes.setSize(9.5f);

    coolShoes.setColor("purple");

    System.out.println( "nerdShoes: " + nerdShoes );

    System.out.println( "nerdShoes style: " + nerdShoes.getStyle() );
    System.out.println( "coolShoes style: " + coolShoes.getStyle() );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A default constructor is identified by not accepting any parameters. My guess about the default values is that they are some placeholder values for your variables. A possible solution might look like this:

```
public Shoe(){ this.style = ""; this.color = ""; this.size = 0; }
```